# Convert String to Int with Integer.parseInt don't works

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm working with JavaEE i need to convert this: `request.getParameter("id")` to `int`. The value of `request.getParameter("id")` is "9" (`String`).
When I'm trying to convert to `int` I have

> java.lang.NumberFormatException

I've tried `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))` and `request.getParameter("id",10)` but it donsen't works...

Any solutions? Thank you.

Comment: are you sure id parameter is a number?try trimming the string

Comment: Is there any leading or trailing spaces? If there is, you would need to `trim()` it before calling `parseInt()`

Comment: Hidden characters? Try trimming the string: `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id").trim())`. If that doesnt work maybe try printing out the character codes in the string.

Comment: Incredible - At least three persons had the same idea at the same time - trim the string.

Comment: @VictorStafusa I'm wondering if OP failed to `trim()` the string.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete full proof code would be

```
    String idString = request.getParameter("id");
    if(idString != null) {
        try {
            System.out.println(idString.trim()); // print to verify
            int idInt = Integer.parseInt(idString.trim());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nbe) {
            nbe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check whether String returned by `getParameter()` is **null** or not then  check whether it is **empty** (`""`) String or not then use `Integer.parseInt()`.

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
    if(null != id && !("".equals(id))) {
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(id.trim());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```